# Detect when animation is done

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So this is my spin the bottle animation:

```
public static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
private int lastAngle = -1;
private ImageView bottle;
private void spinTheBottle() {

        int angle = RANDOM.nextInt(3600 - 360) + 360;
        float pivotX = bottle.getWidth() / 2;
        float pivotY = bottle.getHeight() / 2;

        final Animation animRotate = new RotateAnimation(lastAngle == -1 ? 0 : lastAngle, angle, pivotX, pivotY);
        lastAngle = angle;
        animRotate.setDuration(1500);
        animRotate.setFillAfter(true);

        bottle.startAnimation(animRotate);
    }
```

How can I detect when the animation is done? I tried adding `Animator.AnimatorListener`, but that does not execute at all:

```
Animator.AnimatorListener listener = new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            Toast.makeText(FlasketutenActivity.this, "onAnimationStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            Toast.makeText(FlasketutenActivity.this, "onAnimationEnd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            Toast.makeText(FlasketutenActivity.this, "onAnimationCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            Toast.makeText(FlasketutenActivity.this, "onAnimationRepeat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

Any tips?

Comment: Could you add your code when you add AnimatorListener?

Comment: @CôngHải I have already done that? `Animator.AnimatorListener listener = new Animator.AnimatorListener() {`is the only thing I have.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating the listener, but not assigning it to your animation. Try calling setAnimationListener on your animation object like this:

```
animRotate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    //Listener methods
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first.Keep the ImageView witch and height above of zero at time

```
    rotateAnimation.setDuration(1500);
        rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        rotateAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationStart: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationRepeat: ");
            }
        });
        view.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

it is working in my project.

But I use the animation always in xmls,it is Easy to operate and relatively by code.

Animation and Animator is not a same things.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your listener that you have created to the animation

```
animRotate.setAnimationListener(listener);
```